# LLVM LIT: Is it possible to pass user defined parameter into a test script?

Tags: testing, parameters, llvm

Do somebody know how to parametrize a llvm-lit script? I need to pass some environment variable value into a script to use it inside command line of some tool.

For example, test script could have the following line:

```
// RUN: some-tool $SOME_ENV_VAR
```

I need to pass SOME_ENV_VAR value somehow.

According to the [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/lit.html) for llvm-lit there is an option **-D** or **--param**, but is is unclear how to access this user defined parameter inside a script.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The -D option in llvm-lit is used for passing in parameters like use_gmalloc, etc. What are you specifically trying to perform?

Comment: I need to insert an environment variable value into command line of command which is called from test script (see example in the text above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're able to modify the lit.cfg script (or the script used to generate the config), you can use all the flexibility of Python in there.  For example, you can add:

`some_var = os.environ.get('SOME_ENV_VAR', '')`

Then you can add find-replace tuples:

`config.substitutions.append(('%some_var', some_var))`

Now whenever you have %some_var appear in a RUN line, lit will substitute the value of the environment variable as it was when your test suite began.

Comment: @PiligrimGrey Glad to hear it :)  I would appreciate an upvote and acceptance on the answer if you think it fits the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I have too small reputation and I am not allowed to upvote your answer. I have already tried to do that. Strange rule actually.

Answer (score 1):

Eric's solution is a valid one and I had been using it in my macOS and Linux projects until I encountered that passing environment variables does not work on Windows.

A more portable solution is to use Lit's own [-D/--params](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/lit.html#cmdoption-lit-d) option:

```
-D NAME[=VALUE], --param NAME[=VALUE]

Add a user defined parameter NAME with the given VALUE (or the empty string if not given). The meaning and use of these parameters is test suite dependent.
```

Example: `lit ... --param SOME_VAR=Foo ...`

In `lit.cfg` the parameters can be accessed through `lit_config` global variable as follows:

```
some_var = lit_config.params['SOME_VAR']
config.substitutions.append(('%some_var', some_var))
```

Then in your tests, you can use `%some_var`.

Background for my answer: I use GitHub Actions (GitHub's CI solution) that runs PowerShell on its Windows machines and there is no support for env variables in PowerShell.